# iOS crash when I try to dismiss a modal

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, modalviewcontroller

I modal a controller with a modal transition animation. But when I try to dismiss the controller, the program crash. And Xcode didn't log any message.

It's something wrong with my transition animation. When I delete the transition code, it runs well.

so what's wrong with my code?

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    _transitionContext = transitionContext;
    UIView *toView = [transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextToViewKey];
    UIView *fromView = [transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewKey];
    CALayer *toVcLayer = [CALayer layer];
    toVcLayer.frame = toView.layer.frame;
    [toVcLayer addSublayer:toView.layer];

    _transformLayer = [CATransformLayer layer];
    _transformLayer.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    [_transformLayer addSublayer:fromView.layer];
    CATransform3D ct = CATransform3DIdentity;
    ct = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
    ct = CATransform3DRotate(ct, M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    toVcLayer.transform = ct;
    [_transformLayer addSublayer:toVcLayer];

    CATransform3D at = CATransform3DIdentity;
    at = CATransform3DRotate(at, M_PI, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:at];
    animation.duration = 1.0;
    animation.delegate = self;
    [_transformLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

    [transitionContext.containerView.layer addSublayer:_transformLayer];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    [_transitionContext.containerView addSubview:[_transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextToViewKey]];
    [_transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably lies with moving layers between other layers. You're trying to insert layers that already have a superlayer somewhere else. I don't know why it doesn't crash already when presenting but it's no surprise it does on dismiss.

When dismissing view controllers, their state is different. Mainly, `toView` is already subview of `containerView`. It was `fromView` when presenting after all. With your code view/layer hierarchy gets pretty tangled and finally leads to a crash.

Solution is pretty simple. Instead of creating separate `transformLayer` that holds other layers and animating it. Animate each layer separately. Example:

```
-(void)animateTransition(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    _transitionContext = transitionContext;
    UIView *toView = [transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextToViewKey];
    UIView *fromView = [transitionContext viewForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewKey];

    if (toView.superview == nil)
        [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toView];

    const NSTimeInterval duration = 1.0;
    const CGFloat translationX = 400.0;

    toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(translationX, 0.0, 0.0);

    CABasicAnimation *toAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    toAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
    toAnimation.duration = duration;
    toAnimation.delegate = self;

    CABasicAnimation *fromAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    fromAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-translationX, 0.0, 0.0];
    fromAnimation.duration = duration;

    [fromView addAnimation:fromAnimation forKey:nil];
    [toView addAnimation:toAnimation forKey:nil];
}

-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation*)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    [_transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been confused with this problem for a long  time.